# Use PopupExtensions.ShowPopupAsync function in Custom Control in MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I created a custom control in MAUI that must work if user select with a click or tap, a Popup must show with some content, let's say for example a Calculator instead a Keyboard. I'm using  **CommunityToolkit.Maui**. But the sentence

```
var popup = new PickerControl();
var result = await PopupExtensions.ShowPopupAsync<PickerControl>(this, popup);
```

throw me an error because `this` in inside the control and expects a `Page`, so  need to know how handle the page or parent page in the same control. Picker control is the Popup with the content.
The code:

```
public partial class EntryCalculator : Frame
{
    TapGestureRecognizer _tapGestureRecognizer;
    public EntryCalculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      }
///Properties here

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    }

    
    private async static void IsDisplayPickerPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var controls = (EntryCalculator)bindable;
        if (newValue != null)
        {
            if ((bool)newValue)
            {
                var popup = new PickerControl();
                var response = PopupExtensions.ShowPopupAsync<PickerControl>(this, popup);
                
               if (response != null && response is decimal)
                {
                    controls.Value = (decimal)response;
                }               
            }
        }
    } 
///... other methods
```

Comment: use `App.Current.MainPage`

Comment: Should work, but as custom control I though use it in more than one page (not only the Main Page)

Comment: I think that Jason has a point here. MainPage always exists and Popups are always pushed on the top. It might actually work. Did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you can get the current page from the navigation stack:

If you use the shell:

```cs
Page currentpage = Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
```

If you use the NavigationPage:

```cs
Page currentpage = Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
```

Or just only use:`Page currentpage = App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();`. The `App.Current.MainPage` will be the `Shell` or the `NavigationPage`, it depends on what you used in your project.

In addition, you can get the current page from the custom control. Such as:

```cs
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the page to which an element belongs
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The page.</returns>
    /// <param name="element">Element.</param>
    public static Page GetParentPage (this VisualElement element)
    {
        if (element != null) {
            var parent = element.Parent;
            while (parent != null) {
                if (parent is Page) {
                    return parent as Page;
                }
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case works the implentation of `ViewExtensions` class, because I have this custom controls in a different library. Thanks