# Getting an error in CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views Popup in Contentview

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Getting bellow error whtn i trying to show popup in MAUI contentview

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1929  'SettingOptions' does not contain a definition for 'ShowPopupAsync' and 
the best extension method overload 'PopupExtensions.ShowPopupAsync<SettingOptions> 
(Page, 
 SettingOptions, CancellationToken)' requires a receiver of type 
'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Page'  inSisMobileApp (net8.0-android), inSisMobileApp 
(net8.0-ios)    



public partial class SettingOptions : ContentView
{

private async void TextBgColorTap(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
   
   var popup = new ColorPickerPopUp();
    var result = await this.ShowPopupAsync(this,popup);
  
  
    string res = result as string;
    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
}
}
```

Comment: The ShowPopupAsync method extension from PopupExtensions expects a Page object as its receiver, but you're attempting to call it on this from within a class that inherits from ContentView, not Page.

Comment: Also, check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74786533/use-popupextensions-showpopupasync-function-in-custom-control-in-maui